# What is the difference between "plan on going" and "plan of going"

Tags: idioms

Can someone explain why there are 2 different prepositions. The basic meaning appears to be the same in the example sentences. There are only 6000 search hits on Google for the phrase "plan of going" compared to 6,000,000 for "plan on going" but they are enough to to make me think. Is there a grammar rule that I just can't see?

> I'm not against your **plan of going** to Morocco.
>
> I **plan on going** to Loterie Farms via Royal Caribbean shore
>   excursion next month.

Comment: Note that "plan" is two different parts of speech in your two examples.  In the first, "plan" is a noun.  In the second, it's a verb. So you can't say the meaning is the same: one is a thing (noun) and one is an action (verb).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the difference between your two examples is that in the first plan is a noun, but a verb in the second. I don't know if there's a particular rule I could point to, but I'd only use 'of' in a noun phrase like "the plan of [doing something]".

In a verb phrase it should be 'on': "She plans on [doing something]"